# Searching and replacing a block of XML formatted text in Bash

Tags: regex, xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have been trying to figure out how to search a block of XML formatted text and modify it in Bash. The file I want to process is a simulation file with XML fomatting. Assume that the file contains multiple blocks of XML stataments as:

```
<mote>
  <breakpoints />
  <interface_config>
    org.contikios.cooja.interfaces.Position
    <x>0.0</x>
    <y>75.0</y>
    <z>0.0</z>
  </interface_config>
  <interface_config>
    org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.interfaces.MspClock
    <deviation>1.0</deviation>
  </interface_config>
  <interface_config>
    org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.interfaces.MspMoteID
    <id>4</id>
  </interface_config>
  <motetype_identifier>sky2</motetype_identifier>
</mote>
```

What I want to search is a block of XML statements here:

```
<id>4</id>
  </interface_config>
  <motetype_identifier>sky2</motetype_identifier>
```

And replace it with

```
<id>4</id>
  </interface_config>
  <motetype_identifier>sky3</motetype_identifier>
```

Rest of the XML statements before and after these statements will remain unchanged. This will enable me to change the mote type Node 4 from sky2 to sky3 in a script in Bash.

Comment: You need to let us know what you have tried and general suggestion would be to not use `regex` approach for this and use a `XML` syntax aware tool for this

Comment: I used:


    sed -i -e 's/<id>'$NODE_ID'<\/id>\n<\/interface_config>\n<motetype_identifier>sky2<\/motetype_identifier>/<id>'$NODE_ID'<\/id>\n<\/interface_config>\n<motetype_identifier>sky3<\/motetype_identifier>/g' SimulationFile

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -u "//mote[interface_config/id='4']/motetype_identifier" -v 'sky3' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<mote>
  <breakpoints/>
  <interface_config>
    org.contikios.cooja.interfaces.Position
    <x>0.0</x>
    <y>75.0</y>
    <z>0.0</z>
  </interface_config>
  <interface_config>
    org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.interfaces.MspClock
    <deviation>1.0</deviation>
  </interface_config>
  <interface_config>
    org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.interfaces.MspMoteID
    <id>4</id>
  </interface_config>
  <motetype_identifier>sky3</motetype_identifier>
</mote>
```

If you want to edit file.xml inplace, add option -L.

See: `xmlstarlet ed --help`